Observing data from the SharedViewmodel on two different fragments does not work correctly
I am filtering data in a bottomsheet that can be open in two different fragment in the different activities, when I filter the data on Fragment A, they save on viewmodel, but when I enter to Fragment B and observe the data they are null. If I go back to the Fragment A the data are saved and filtered, how to fix this issue?
I am using Dagger Hilt so I think that I should not use BaseViewmodelFactory.
This is the ViewModel:
@HiltViewModel
class CarViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    private val _carFilters = MutableLiveData<CarFilters>().apply {
        value = CarFilters()
    }
    val carFilters: LiveData<CarFilters> get() = _carFilters

    private val _dates = MutableLiveData<DateFilters?>()
    val date: MutableLiveData<DateFilters?> get() = _dates

    fun updateDates(dates: DateFilters) {
        _dates.value = dates
    }

    fun updateFilters(updatedFilters: CarFilters) {
        _carFilters.value = updatedFilters
    }
}

also i am careful on this, this is how i call the viewmodel on each fragment and bottomsheet:
    private val viewModel: CarViewModel by activityViewModels()
    
   // my observable :
    
    viewModel.carFilters.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){...}


Please check the viewModel instance, I think you have 2 viewModel instances
